# What's the opposite of `/` in Command Prompt (nushell)?

Tags: command-line, terminal, navigation, nushell

Whenever I accidentally press <kbd>`/`</kbd> +<kbd>Return</kbd>. I end up at the root of the current drive, or `C:\`.

Is there an opposite operation? A shortcut to last location? Anything?

I'm using `nushell`, on Windows 10.

Comment: That’s not standard Command Prompt behavior in the first place. If you add some more details (which shell, which terminal emulator), a more precise answer may be possible.

Comment: Some other shells, like `bash` (common on Linux) allow `cd -` to go to the previous directory, as a cheap alternative to bash's `pushd` / `popd` without needing to plan ahead.  Or `cd` somewhere and `mv` some files back to or from where you just were with `mv ~-/foo.* .` (where `~-` expands like `$OLDPWD`, not limited to `cd`).  Bash is available for Windows (cygwin or mingw), but you're not using it so this isn't an answer.  (Oh, apparently `cd -` works in nushell after `cd` normally, see Daniel B's asnwer for this possible bug in Nushell.)

Comment: A total guess, but does `exit` work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Nushell book](https://www.nushell.sh/book/coming_from_bash.html), you can go to the *previous* directory using:

```
cd -
```

That’s `cd` and a dash.

This behavior was previously not available for “auto cd” (changing directory just by typing a path). [It is now](https://github.com/nushell/nushell/pull/6019), coming with a future *nushell* release (probably 0.66.0).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does *not* work after `/`.  (Just tested in my install.)  Works fine if you `cd` to root, but not if you just use the `/` shortcut directly.

Comment: @Joe You’re right, this isn’t working. Very surprising. I files a bug report for this behavior mismatch.

Comment: My bug report has already been addressed, so this will probably be in the next _nushell_ release.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such shortcut.

The most you can do is select the last folder
from the previous prompt and paste it to `cd` to it.

To remember a folder, you could use the
[pushd command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd)
together with the
[popd command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/popd).

To remember a folder :

```
pushd
```

To return to the remembered folder :

```
popd
```

These commands use a stack that can remember more than one folder.

Comment: I get the impression this answer is not nushell-specific, as `pushd` and `popd` don't work that way in nushell.  It's correct, though, that there is no such shortcut.